python3 multiprocessing SharedMemory can not solve connecting to existing memory
What I want to accompish is to first run testb.py and create shared memory, then run testc.py and connect to it. Then shutdown testc.py and rerun it and connect to shared memory again. But I stuck at last one.
In another word, I want to create a shared memory in long lifetime code and connect to it from different processes. But when process end and restarts it causes a problem.
testa.py
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory


class CommonDataHandler:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.check_init()

    def check_init(self):
        try:
            self.shared_data_shm = SharedMemory(name='integer', create=False)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            self.create_shared_objects()

    def get_value(self):
        return int.from_bytes(self.shared_data_shm.buf[:4], byteorder='little')
    
    def set_value(self, value):
        self.shared_data_shm.buf[:4] = value.to_bytes(4, byteorder='little')

    def create_shared_objects(self):
        # Create shared memory
        self.shared_data_shm = SharedMemory(name='integer', create=True, size=4)
        # Initialize default values
        value = 11
        # Write packed data to shared memory buffers
        self.shared_data_shm.buf[:4] = value.to_bytes(4, byteorder='little')
        print("Shared objects are created.")

    def disconnect(self):
        self.shared_data_shm.close()
        print("Shared objects are disconnected.")

    def cleanup(self):
        self.shared_data_shm.unlink()
        print("Shared objects are unlinked.")

testb.py
from testa import CommonDataHandler
from time import time, sleep

st = time()
c = CommonDataHandler()
print(f"CommonDataHandler in testb: {time()-st:.6f} seconds")

for i in range(10):
    value = c.get_value()
    print(f"Value: {value}")
    c.set_value(i)
    sleep(1)

c.cleanup()

testc.py
from testa import CommonDataHandler
from time import time, sleep
import os

st = time()
c = CommonDataHandler()
print(f"CommonDataHandler in testc: {time()-st:.6f} seconds")

print(f"Value: {c.get_value()}")

c.disconnect()

# sleep(1)
# os.system("python3 testc.py")

here is the output.
First terminal I run testb.py
py testb.py  Shared objects are created. CommonDataHandler in testb: 0.000350 seconds Value: 11 Value: 0 Value: 1 Value: 2 Value: 3 Value: 4 Value: 5 Value: 6 Value: 7 Value: 8 Shared objects are unlinked.
At the same time in different terminal I run testc.py
CommonDataHandler in testc: 0.000304 seconds Value: 1 Shared objects are disconnected.
And also a warning pops up:
/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:224: UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 1 leaked shared_memory objects to clean up at shutdown warnings.warn('resource_tracker: There appear to be %d '
And again I run it:
Shared objects are created. CommonDataHandler in testc: 0.000390 seconds Value: 11 Shared objects are disconnected.
And same warning.
Also tried with comment lines uncommented and here what it looks like:
CommonDataHandler in testc: 0.000314 seconds Value: 1 Shared objects are disconnected. CommonDataHandler in testc: 0.000280 seconds Value: 2 Shared objects are disconnected. CommonDataHandler in testc: 0.000313 seconds Value: 3 Shared objects are disconnected. CommonDataHandler in testc: 0.000330 seconds Value: 4 Shared objects are disconnected. CommonDataHandler in testc: 0.000317 seconds Value: 5 Shared objects are disconnected. CommonDataHandler in testc: 0.000325 seconds Value: 6 Shared objects are disconnected. CommonDataHandler in testc: 0.000295 seconds Value: 7 Shared objects are disconnected. CommonDataHandler in testc: 0.000302 seconds Value: 8 Shared objects are disconnected. CommonDataHandler in testc: 0.000307 seconds Value: 9 Shared objects are disconnected. Shared objects are created. CommonDataHandler in testc: 0.000375 seconds Value: 11 Shared objects are disconnected.

on linux you have to mark the shared_memory as Track=False if you don't own it.
self.shared_data_shm = SharedMemory(name='integer', create=False, size=0, track=False)

Otherwise the resource tracker will emit this warning telling you that you didn't unlink the resource (which you shouldn't do, because you don't own it).
Lastly i would like to point that your code has unsynchronized access to this shared_memory, and the __init__ method shouldn't unconditionally try to create the shared_memory or you can end up creating the resource without unlinking it at the end if it didn't exist, i would recommend you use sockets or pipes to communicate when is it okay to access this shared memory and when it is not, the whole concept of shared memory is littered with race conditions that you don't have the GIL protecting you from, and for what it is worth you are better off using sockets or pipes.
For versions of python lower than 3.13 you will likely need to unregister the memory manually, as done in unlink

Thank you for the answer, I think your suggestion solves the issue but track feature requires python3.13 and is there any other solution comes to your mind in python3.10? Also I'm building a object tracking system that has backend and frontend. I need some communication bidirectional between backend and frontend. I'm using websockets for now but I am looking for faster way since its a realtime system. This is why I was testing sharedmemory, is there any suggestions can you give me about it? There are 3 processes runs simultaneously and all in python, GUI is coded with PyQT5.

@AlperenÖlçer you'll have to unregister the shared_memory from the memory tracker yourself, by calling unregister as done in unlink here https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6a2f12a754d6be016c8abda5f8d432795574b594/Lib/multiprocessing/shared_memory.py#L236

@AlperenÖlçer depending on the use-case sockets can be faster than shared memory, for example say you want to transfer 100 MB block of data, if you transfer them over sockets then both processes could be writing and reading to the socket concurrently, while if you use shared-memory then you will have to lock the entire buffer until the writer finishes then signal over to the reader side to start reading the data, then signaling back to the writer that it can start writing new data, shared_memory is not faster than sockets for a typical server-client application

shared_memory is useful if you don't copy it, for example it can be used an in-place numpy buffers for computations, this way the writer will be writing them while computing them and the reader will be doing operations on them while reading them, which saves the serialization and de-serialization time, they have their uses but not for every application, and it increases the complexity of the application.

@AlperenÖlçer there's also a difference between latency and throughput, shared memory can increase the application's throughput, but it will notably increase the latency, so it is useful in applications that do heavy computations because they only care about throughput, while for typical client-server application latency is likely more important which is why sockets could be better.

Thank you again, I think I'll move on with redis library, by the way I couldn't resolved with unregister but I don't need it now.
